# Musical murder mystery

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, situation, music, history

This is a murder mystery set in an alternate reality that involves siblings of two famous musicians. Your job is to toe the line between reality and imagination, and figure out which of the stated facts are relevant to the case. The ultimate goal is to determine who the murder victim was and who, of course, dunnit.

The crime takes place in the exotic land of nineteen eighty-one. Our first three characters are the brother and two sisters of a musician named **Richard**, age 41. He plays the drums and sometimes sings as well.

- Richard's brother is named Michael, but he goes by **Mike**. He is 33 and plays the French horn in the philharmonic orchestra.
- Richard's younger sister is Teresa, age 37. People call her **Terry**. She’s a palaeontologist who studies woolly mammoths.
- Richard's older sister is Victoria, or **Vicky**. She’s 47. She moved to abroad in her twenties and currently lives with her partner on a farm in Darling Downs, northeastern Australia.

Our remaining candidates are the sister and two brothers of a singer named **Ronald**, age 39. He is originally from America, but currently works as the lead singer of a British group.

- Ronald's sister is Violet, usually known as just **V**. She’s 36 years old. She is a professionally trained musician who sometimes takes on jobs as a backup singer, but her real passion is taking care of her English garden. She is single.
- Ronald's younger brother is Christopher, a.k.a. **Chris**, 38. He’s a guitarist and owns a record shop. He lives in Long Island with his wife and golden retriever.
- Ronald's older brother is Raymond, or **Ray** for short. He’s 43 and is married to Richard's sister Teresa. They live in a town house with their two children.

It is early August. One of the people listed has murdered one of their siblings, and the identity of the culprit has just been revealed on television.

Who was the victim, and who the perpetrator?

Comment: +1 for the "dad joke" :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks to @00Average for the crucial hint and @Stiv for tieing up the loose ends!

Solution:

> Ronald's brother Ray was killed by his sister V.

Thought process:

1. The musicians

> The year is 1981. Richard is 41 years old, drummer and singer.
>  This hints to **Ringo Starr**, born July, 7th, 1940 as Richard Starkey; mainly known as drummer of the beatles but also singer.
>  The second musician is probably **Ronnie James Dio**, born July, 10th, 1942 as Ronald James Padavona; born in the US, and 1981 lead singer of Black Sabbath.

2. The siblings

> Both Ringo Starr and Ronnie James Dio do not have siblings in reality.

3. The murder

> The siblings' initials say **MTV** and **VCR**, both terms connected to television. VCR (Video Cassette Recording) was released in 1972, whereas MTV (Music Television) was first broadcasted on August, 1st, 1981 ("just been revealed").
>  The first song shown on MTV was "Video killed the Radio Star"
>  = V Dio killed the Ray Dio-Starr.

Comment: You've done 90% of the work--for the rest, ask Hans Zimmer, he would know.

Comment: Don't forget Ray is married to Teresa Starr... They're what would once have been called a 'modern couple' in terms of their surname choices...